# Does dynamically importing images using a continuous time interval in React overload memory?

Tags: reactjs, image, memory, lazy-loading, setinterval

I'll give an explanation and then my question is at the very bottom. Below shows the code I'm using to dynamically import 7 images at a 0.5s interval. These images get shown on the website as what appears to be a continuous loop. As they get imported the images get stored in an array at each interval. Once all 7 have been imported it stops dynamically importing and refers to each image inside the array when rendering an image at each interval.

```
import { Image } from 'grommet';
import React from 'react';
import defaultImage from '../../../assets/images/showcase-1.jpg';

const imageCount = 8;

const ImageLooper = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = React.useState(defaultImage);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let index = 2;
        const imageArray = [];
        setInterval(async () => {
            if (index === imageCount) {
                index = 1;
            }
            if (imageArray.length < 8) {
                await import(`../../../assets/images/showcase-${index}.jpg`).then((image) => {
                    imageArray.push(image['default']);
                    setImage(image['default']);
                });
            } else {
                setImage(imageArray[index - 1]);
            }
            index++;
        }, 500);
    }, []);

    return <Image a11yTitle="Example NFT images" width="100%" src={image} radius="70px" loading="lazy" />;
};

export default ImageLooper;
```

When looking at the chrome developer tools and also the equivalent tool inside safari, the Resources value (circled below) continuously increases with each image render. And if you look at the name column it shows duplicates of each of the 7 image names:
[image]

If you look at the chrome sources section, however, it shows only one of each image:
[image]

**My question is, does that Resources value in the network section equal the total amount of images now stored in memory? Or is it just an accumulation of all requests since the website loaded? Basically, will my code cause a memory overload, or not?**

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` with `setTimeout`, as you have it, could very well cause a memory leak, as you never clear the timeout when the component unmounts. This is easily handled using a `ref`

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
// ...
const timerRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  // ...
  timerRef = window.setTimeout(() => {
    // some function
  }, 500);

  return () => {
    // Use optional chaining, on the off chance 'current'
    // isn't defined. The 'clearTimeout' will ignore
    // it if it's undefined.
    window.clearTimeout(timerRef?.current);
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the tip. The main question is regarding that 'Resources value' in the browser developer tools though. That value keeps increasing, I don't know whether there are only 14 images stored in memory (shown in the dev tools Sources section) or the amount shown by that Resources value (in the Network section).

Comment: Well, you are loading a number of new images on each iteration. Since the image tags are never removed from the DOM, I would think that each applied image would be loaded into memory, and never fully GC'd. But I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Sure, yeah it's hard to tell whether the image tags get overwritten by the next image or not.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think they do, so much as just dynamically switching the source.